# go install not creating binary of a package while go get is able to

Tags: go

I am on go version go1.11.2 linux/amd64. When the package [godog](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/godog/) is installed using `go get github.com/DATA-DOG/godog/`, `godog` executable is created inside $GOPATH/bin/. All fine till now.

I am creating an application `myApp` that resides at $GOPATH/src/ in which under the folder vendor, godog package is added. When I try to create a binary out of vendor-ed package, an archive file is created inside `$GOPATH/pkg/linux_amd64/myApp/vendor/github.com/DATA-DOG/` as `godog.a`

How can I create a binary in this scenario? I do not want to do `go get` again just for the binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go install` does not automatically install apps in `vendor` folders, but you may specify a vendored path explicitly if you wish so. So simply run:

```
go install myApp/vendor/github.com/DATA-DOG/godog/cmd/godog
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I am missing something. When I execute the above from `$GOPATH/src/`, I am getting the following error: `can't load package: package myApp/vendor/github.com/DATA-DOG/cmd/godog: cannot find package "myApp/vendor/github.com/DATA-DOG/cmd/godog" in any of:
        /home/ubuntu/go/src/myApp/vendor/github.com/DATA-DOG/cmd/godog (from $GOROOT)
        /home/ubuntu/.go/src/myApp/vendor/github.com/DATA-DOG/cmd/godog (from $GOPATH)`

Comment: Use the package name you want to install. If path is not `myApp`, obviously use what you have.

Comment: When I used `go install myApp/vendor/github.com/DATA-DOG/godog`, it created `godog.a` inside `$GOPATH/pkg/` not the executable. I am very sorry to sound this stupid. Can you please spell it out for me what I am missing?

Comment: You have to provide a `main` package, non-main packages are not installed into executables. I edited my answer as I left out a folder from the path, it should be: `myApp/vendor/github.com/DATA-DOG/godog/cmd/godog`

Comment: I am still facing the issue as I mentioned earlier. One thing to note is, as I mentioned, since `go get` is able to create a binary but `go install` is not.

Comment: Please check where the `main` package is in your vendored `DATA-DOG` folder, and tell me.

Comment: Thank you for asking that question! I finally figured out what was causing the issue. The culprit is `dep`. Here is what I found. I used `dep` to vendor dependencies. When it did `godog`, it didn't download the file `main.go` inside `cmd/godog` from github. I have no idea why it did that. When I manually copied the file in to `vendor` folder, it installed the executable! I am accepting your answer. But do you know why this is so?

Comment: @iamthadiyan I would guess because none of your packges refer to this `cmd/godog` folder / package, so `dep` decided it is not needed.

Comment: oh I see! Let me see if anything can be done about that.